# Why is BackgroundWorker exception not handled?

Tags: c#

This is the code that throws exception.
It is in class called `GitHelper` which is called by class `GitProgressDialog` it it's `bw_DoWork` method.

```
public class GitHelper
{
 ....
            if (!Run(commands[i]))
            {
                var e = new InvalidOperationException(Error);
                e.Data["stepIndex"] = i;
                throw e;
            }
     ...
```

This is code that is handling exceptions:

```
public partial class GitProgressDialog : Form
{
 ...
    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {

        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Success = false;
            errorStepIndex = (int)e.Error.Data["stepIndex"];
            SetError(e.Error.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            Success = true;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Error is happening in this line:

```
errorStepIndex = (int)e.Error.Data["stepIndex"];
```

System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I guess Data is not set well? But why?
It works for me from withing Visual Studio with and without debugger.
For client it activates the main exception handling routine which logs it and closes the app.

Comment: Maybe it's a different exception and not the `InvalidOperationException` you throw manually, but one thrown in e.g. `Run(commands[i])`?

Comment: There is only one line of code in GitHelper class which throws the exception and thus it's always InvalidOperationException

Comment: Well obviously it's not like that, because then it would work. How about checking if `e.Error.Data` is set and has a value in `e.Error.Data["stepIndex"]`, just to avoid the `NullReferenceException` and log the `e.Error.Message` in any case.

Comment: Thanks I will do that.

Comment: You have to declare your own Exception derived type to do this properly, what you are doing now is far too dangerous.  Especially since InvalidOperationException is so likely to also be thrown just because you use a thread, you for example get it simply by accessing a UI control.  Then use the `is` operator to verify that you got the exception that you expected.

Comment: Thanks, I'll implement that too.

Comment: Make sure you are not passing "Error" as null in following : new InvalidOperationException(Error);